# PostSharp Express for redistrubution

Tags: c#, licensing, postsharp

We have a product, that generates the source code (C#/java/IOS) from a given model and settings. The generated code is delivered to the client for his own enhancements.

I want to get rid of large pieces of code (C#) to log the audit details like method entered, exited, exception handling using PostSharp. The free version (Expression Edition) serves my need.

However, when we deliver the code to the client, it should be clean, no traces of our product / organization, as if it is written and developed by the programmers in the client organization.

For this scenario, can I use the PostSharp (Express edition)? Does PostSharp includes any info about the original consumer? or does it requires re-installation/registration on each client box where the source code is extended/compiled?

Thanks

Comment: "should be clean, no traces of our product / organization" : What exactly does this mean? The only way to write a product with "no traces" is by not writing it. Confused.

Comment: I mean there shouldn't be a comment/log info about our organization. We are delivering the complete source code, with no ownership of any parts of the generated code. But when I reflect the dll generated after PostSharp (compiled in my box with PostSharp trial version), it has some files stating that trial version licensed to xxx and code generated from machine xxx.

Comment: Do you deliver only the source code to your client, or the source code and the compiled dll? PostSharp doesn't change your source code, only the resulting assembly dll.

Comment: We deliver the source code and the required dlls (including PostSharp ones) to compile. I am little wary if PostSharp needs to be installed for compiling in client boxes, and/or holds any licensing info pertaining to our company, the original license holder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

If you add PostSharp to the project, then PostSharp becomes a part of the build process - every developer who tries to build the project will have to install PostSharp and register a license (express or commercial).

In your case, there will be no info about your company redistributed with the source code.
But your client, who receives the source code from you, will have to install PostSharp during the build process and register his own license.